# Referencing a 'faux parent' s properties...?

Tags: php, loading, parent

I've been wondering about the following for a while:
I'm using a construct of loading some (,in this case 'tool'-) classes into properties of a 'parent' or 'controller' class. More concrete:

```
    class a
    {
        public $b;
        public $c;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->b = new b();
            $this->c = new c();
        }
    }
    class b
    {
        // Properties and methods of b.
    }
    class c
    {
        // Properties and methods of c.
    }
    $a = new a();
```

The relationship between a and b (and c) is not one of (respectively) 'parent child' as there can only one instance of a. So far so good, however: at the moment I'm accessing members of class a in classes b or c by getting a local reference of a through calling 'global'... So:

```
    class a
    {
        public $b;
        public $c;
        public $a_property = 'something something';

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->b = new b();
            $this->c = new c();
        }
    }
    class b
    {
        public function test()
        {
            global $a;
            echo $a->a_property;
        }
    }
    class c
    {
        // Properties and methods of c.
    }
    $a = new a();
    $a->b->test();
```

This is a: ugly (I think) and b: (I can't find any documentation/reference on it anymore but) I believe that as of PHP 5(.?) the following should be possible:

```
    class a
    {
        public $b;
        public $c;
        public $a_property = 'something something';

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->b = new b();
            $this->c = new c();
        }
    }
    class b
    {
        public function test()
        {
            echo $this->a_property;
        }
    }
    class c
    {
        // Properties and methods of c.
    }
    $a = new a();
    $a->b->test();
```

This doesn't work... though the server is running PHP 5.3.6...

Occam's razor: I'm probably mistaken about the functionality...! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since `b` doesn't extend `a` even though `a` instanciated it, it should be able to access the property via `echo a::$a_property;` because now `b` as scope to the `a` class.

Comment: Hi AlienWebguy,

Thanks for your reply! However: I've never seen the scope resolution operator and object accessor used in combination...and it doesn't work... (And where's the variable '$'..?) Also: yes, "a::$a_property" would work if "$a_property" was declared 'static'... This, I would rather not do...

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to access the "a_property" by using "$this->a_property", B should extend a.

```
class b extends a
```

Otherwise, you just make a composition and composition doesn't permet to give access to members of the two classes.

What is the error message ?

Comment: Hi Triomen,

Thanks for your reply!
Yes, that would of course work but, like I said, class 'a' should not be 'parent' to 'b' and/or 'c'... 

Error is (Good question! ;-)): "Undefined property: b::$val"
Telling me: 'b' is not aware of 'a'... Right!?

Comment: Two things. Either, A should be the parent of B OR you can make $a_property accessible as a static.
"$this" references a class of type "B" and not "A"
If A can be instanciate only one time, couldn't it be a parent class with the "singleton" patern ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should read about [inheritance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) in PHP :)

**EDIT:**

Sample code:

```
class a{
        public $a_property = 'something something';

}
class b extends a{
        public function test()
        {
            echo $this->a_property;
        }          
}

    $b = new b();
    $b->test();
```

Comment: Hi Mateusz,
Thanks for your reply! Yes, I've been aware of that and have thus (in the example posted) used the 'declaring it global' method. My question was about whether what I thought 'what should be possible (as of version 5.?)' - 'Because I read it somewhere.' - is true or not... ;-)